# How to parent a 3d character to a kick scooter bike?

Tags: constraints

The kick scooter is not rigged but I thought of setting it's child of constraints to the character's root bone and I'm  not sure of it because I don't know which to move (whether the scooter or the character's root bone) during animation

Comment: yes you could parent the root of the character to the bike, then move the bike, you can also give Child Of constraints to the hand so that they stick to the handlebars

Comment: Thanks also for even talking about parenting the hands before asking